# Passing Data Back to Components

Tags: ember.js

I currently have a component a couple of components. One is a component to display all my table view data, and inside of that component, is another to display the search fields. They look like so:

```
{{#table-display model=model}}

    <table class="data-table">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email Address</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       {{#each filteredModel as |contact| }}
         {{#link-to 'contacts.edit' contact tagName="tr"}}
           <td>{{ current-status model=contact }}</td>
           <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
           <td><em>{{ contact.name }}</em></td>
           <td><em>{{ contact.email }}</em></td>
         {{/link-to}}
       {{/each}}
       </tbody>
     </table>

{{/table-display}}
```

Then inside of the `table-display` component, I have my search filter input.

```
{{input value=filterString placeholder="Search Contacts" }}
```

The table filtering works if I put the table into the `table-display` component, but not if it's just within the component. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could ou show me the "not working" example, I'm not sure to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few ways to get the fitleredModel data to flow out of the component, the idiomatic way is to use HTMLBars blocked params.

Inside table-display's template:

```
...
{{input value=filterString placeholder="Search Contacts" }}
...
{{yield filteredModel}}
```

And then in your main template:

```
{{#table-display model=model as |filteredModel|}}
   ...
   {{#each filteredModel as |contact|}}
   ...
   {{/each}}
{{/table-display}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I get a "Build Error" when I use `model as |filteredModel|`

Comment: @WebDevDude: can you provide some more details on the build error? Ember version? Here is a working Twiddle http://ember-twiddle.com/14476d459de8de462137 and Gist https://gist.github.com/xkb/14476d459de8de462137